# Angularjs: Object property value does not update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I know there are multiple questions related to my issue, but I still have problem fixing this. I have the following html and JavaScript code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="Demo">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous">      
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">     
    </script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="AppController">

        <input type="" name="" ng-model="docs[1].value">
        {{m3.value}}
        {{m4}}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('Demo', []);

        app.controller(
            "AppController",
            function( $scope ) {

                $scope.docs=[{value:"first doc"}, {value:"second doc"}];                

                $scope.m3=$scope.docs[1]; 
                $scope.m4=$scope.docs[1].value;

            }
        );


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I type in the input, the `m3.value` gets updated but `m4` does not! I can't figure out why this is happening. Any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the way I solved it is to add a watcher to m3.value:

```
$scope.$watch('m3.value', function(){
     console.log('Changing');
     $scope.m4 = $scope.m3.value;
});
```

And now $scope.m4 updates.

Comment: This is the only way that worked for me, the ng-change that you suggested does not fit to what I want. Please note that the code I provided here is a simplified version of my original code

Comment: I shown ng-change just to show you that modal is updating and not suggested for your code use

Answer (score 4):

**Statement 1 :**

```
$scope.m3=$scope.docs[1];
```

This statement storing the reference for model `docs[1]`

so, `{{m3.value}}` will get updated model value.

**Statement 2 :**

```
$scope.m4=$scope.docs[1].value;
```

This statement copying the actual primitive value.

so, `{{m4}}` still get old value

Comment: Thanks, but how should I bind to the docs[1].value in the controller then?

Comment: @user1512681 you can use `$scope.docs[1].value` or `m3.value` to get the updated value in controller

Comment: (off topic) is it still a two-way binding? will it be part of watchers?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN $scope.docs[1].value does not give me the updated value.

Comment: @user1512681 check this one . https://plnkr.co/edit/sZ2hKSzolTOzZG6HcupN?p=preview